# NodeJS - Multiple Router files

Tags: node.js

I have 2 router files. One is for view routing and other for api requests.

I am trying to set the routing using:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index'); //View Router
var api = require('./routes/api'); //API Router

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', api);
```

This fails in case of /api requests. If I remove one of the routings, the other works.

I also tried,

```
routes(app);
api(app);
```

But this fails too. Any idea what might be the issue? Please let me know in case additional details are required.

routers/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Promise = require('bluebird');
var nforce = require('nforce');
var org = require('../lib/connection');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'App' });
});

router.get('/accounts', function(req, res, next){
console.log(org);
    res.render('partials/' + name);
    org.query({query: 'Select Id, Name, Type, Industry, Rating From Account Order By LastModifiedDate DESC'})
        .then(function(results){
            console.log(results);
            res.render('accounts', {title: 'Accounts', records: results.records});
        });
});

router.get('/partials/:name', function(req, res, next){
    var name = req.params.name;
console.log(name);
  res.render('partials/' + name);
});

router.get('/api/:name', function(req, res, next){
    var name = req.params.name;
console.log(name);
  res.render('api/' + name);
});
module.exports = router;
```

/routers/api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Promise = require('bluebird');
var nforce = require('nforce');
var org = require('../lib/connection');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/getAccounts', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('in API router...');
    org.query({query: 'Select Id, Name, Type, Industry, Rating From Account Order By LastModifiedDate DESC'})
    .then(function(results){
        console.log(results);
        res.json({'accounts': results.records});
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You will have to show us the routers themselves and show us what URLs you are testing them with.

Comment: added the routers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe wrong but i see problem in this route.

`router.get('/api/:name', function(req, res, next){})`

It will match `/api/cuteName` and it also will match `/api/getAccounts`.

So you need to make routes more clear. I would suggest to change route inside `index.js` to be all something like `/main/`.

And all API routes move to `api.js`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: silly me... :( that was the exact issue...i added the api path in index file as well...removed it and it worked ...thanks for your time :D

Comment: Np.Glad it helped you.